# How Do I Finish The Last Mission?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

How do I finish the last mission on Assassins Creed Black Flag? I need help on the first part where you have to do something with the two Man O' Wars.

Answer (score 2):

"Before you begin the mission, there will be two man of war ships blocking your path. If you are strong enough, then you could try beating them. However, if not, then check your map. There should be a shark icon. Go to it and begin harpooning. After the mini cutscene, return to the ship. Immediately go back to the man of war ships, they should be occupied with another ship and won't notice you, carefully slip pass them and begin the mission."

[Click here, for a walkthrough. (Spoilers)](http://m.ca.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Ever_a_Splinter)

Or you can fully upgrade your ship and take them both on. :)